# Specifying RGB color in a colorbox - tcolorbox package

Tags: color, tcolorbox, colorbox

I tried to specify a RGB color in a color box in this way, but it doesn't recognize RGB, only rgb that is a different thing.

How can I specify a RGB color in a color box?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{equation}
\theta(t) = \frac{k_t \,
\colorbox{yellow!40!white}{$\displaystyle ~
v(s)
~\vphantom{\int}$} 
- (R + L \, s) \,
\colorbox{RGB:red,0;green,127;blue,255}{$\displaystyle ~
\tau_L(s)
~\vphantom{\int}$} 
}
{(R + L \, s) \, (J \, s^2 + b \, s)
+ k_t \, k_e \, s}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the color first using `\definecolor` and then call it where you need it, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0,127,255}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{equation}
\theta(t) = \frac{k_t \,
\colorbox{yellow!40!white}{$\displaystyle ~
v(s)
~\vphantom{\int}$} 
- (R + L \, s) \,
\colorbox{mycolor}{$\displaystyle ~
\tau_L(s)
~\vphantom{\int}$} 
}
{(R + L \, s) \, (J \, s^2 + b \, s)
+ k_t \, k_e \, s}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Another way would be to use `\colorbox[RGB]{0,127,255}{...}` directly.

[image]

Comment: Hello @JasperHabicht thank you very much for your answer.